When would a columnstore index be unsuitable for an OLAP environment with large and wide tables?
Suppose that your SQL Server 2019 machine has a query that hits a disk-based table that is both long (let's say 3,000,000 rows) and wide (let's say 150 columns). Suppose that you retrieve most of the rows and most of the columns. Finally, suppose that the table is infrequently changed. Consider it a typical reporting server table that is only updated once a day.
Are there any circumstances at all where the above conditions apply and a traditional rowstore index would be preferable to a columnstore index, clustered or otherwise?
I worry that I have been sold too easily on columnstore indexes and will begin using them on all of my large and wide tables.


Suppose that you retrieve most of the rows and most of the columns.


Are there any circumstances at all where the above conditions apply and a traditional rowstore index would be preferable to a columnstore index, clustered or otherwise?

Indexes in general don't help you much if you're selecting the table in its entirety (or close to it, in your words above), especially if you're selecting the columns as they are stored and not doing any sort of aggregations, calculations, or manipulations with them.
Since you specifically mentioned this is an OLAP context, if you are doing some sorts of aggregations, then a columnstore index may be able to benefit you with batch mode execution at least:

Batch mode execution is a query processing method that's used to process multiple rows together. Batch mode execution is closely integrated with, and optimized around, the columnstore storage format. Batch mode execution is sometimes known as vector-based or vectorized execution. Queries on columnstore indexes use batch mode execution, which improves query performance typically by two to four times.

And again, given that the majority of the columns will be selected in your queries, you would likely want to make your columnstore index clustered. That way the original table is persisted together in the columnstore, as opposed to a copy of it being maintained in a separate index.

If you're selecting the whole table, then isn't that a great argument for clustered columnstore? The compression for those is supposed to be the best compression that SQL Server has to offer, so it should work wonders for your I/O costs and memory usage.

@J.Mini It's a great argument for defining your columnstore index as clustered, but it still doesn't mean your index is going to be able to do too much for you, especially if you're just selecting the raw data without aggregation etc (as my answered mentioned). "The compression for those is supposed to be the best compression that SQL Server has to offer" - Not necessarily true. It just depends on the data and use cases. Sometimes row or page compression is better. You can use sp_estimate_data_compression_savings to get a rough idea of which one would work best for your table.

I managed to find one case where the rowstore index wins: When you care about uniqueness. Many types of join, but merge joins in particular, become much faster when they know that both sides of the joins have unique values. A rowstore index can provide this knowledge with primary/unique keys, but columnstore indexes cannot offer this.
In cases where you have both such a rowstore index and a columnstore index, I find that the optimiser will usually chose the columnstore index over the rowstore one. Presumably, it correctly estimates that the columnstore index will be much cheaper to scan but wrongly concludes that this will save more effort than using the rowstore index's uniqueness.
There is also something relevant about hash matches but I'm unsure what. I find that a hash join with a rowstore index will cause the predicate to be passed down in to the index scan but a hash join with a columnstore index will have the filter be an explicit operator in the execution plan. The latter is much slower.
